# Program can't find explicitly linked DLL

Tags: c, dll, msbuild

I am trying to modify a C program that explictly links to a DLL to connect to a Driver for an amplifier. It came with the DLL file, the C source code and a pre-compiled executable. The executable runs fine, but when I re-built it using the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, it can't find the library (errorcode 126). I verified that the path is correct, the DLL is where the program is looking for it.

Here is the part of the program that loads the DLL:

```
TCHAR Path[ MAX_PATH ];
...
TCHAR Hardcoded[255] = _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\TMSiSDK.dll");
Path[0] = 0 ; // When debugging, use the locally build lib
lstrcat(Path, Hardcoded);
...
LibHandle = LoadLibrary(Path);
```

And here is the command I used to build it in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017:

```
cl sampler.c
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

It's my first time using a program with DLL-s and I'm also not used to developing under Windows, so excuse my newbieness.

Comment: After over five years as a member, it's really time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and that you read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons for possible down-votes of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved in the meantime: for some reason, the default Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 was the one for 32 bits on my 64 bit system, which is why the DLL was not recognised as a valid DLL.